# Yii2: How to change font-family of Select2 widget

Tags: css, yii2, jquery-select2-4, font-family

I have a [select2](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2) widget and I need to change its font-family.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'my_number')
    ->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'items' => ['One' => 'One', 'Two' => 'Two', 'Three' => 'Three'],
        'class' => 'form-control',
]) ?>
```

Bootstrap doesn't have a class to change it so I think I need to change its style.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using [Kartik Select2](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) and to customize the `Font-family` for the select2 you need to update the following classes that are added in the `select2-krajee.css` file.They are divided into 2 groups if you want to change the `font-family`

## Changing Font Family

#### For the Placeholder and selected Option

```
.select2-container--krajee .select2-selection{
   font-family:Roboto, sans-serif !important;
}
```

#### For the Drop-down Options

```
.select2-container--krajee .select2-results__option{
   font-family:Roboto, sans-serif !important;
}
```

## Changing Font color/size

#### For the Selected option

```
.select2-container--krajee .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{
    color:red !important;
}
```

#### For the Default Placeholder

```
.select2-container--krajee .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__placeholder{
    color:red !important;
}
```

For changing the color for the dropdown option the same class is used that is listed for the `font-family` option in the first section on top, i.e `.select2-container--krajee .select2-results__option`.

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

you can add style to it like follows:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'my_number')
->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'items' => ['One' => 'One', 'Two' => 'Two', 'Three' => 'Three'],
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'options' => ['style' => 'font:yourfontfamilly'],
]) ?>
```

Comment: In this way, you are changing the style of the hidden element. Why do you need to change the style of something you can't see?